# Why my jupyter doesn't have run cell option?

Tags: python, jupyter

I want to run a python file in Jupyter notebook to see a plot from matplotlib.pyplot in the code. The file is already in the list in home. When I opened the file, it had only 4 options -- File, Edit, View, Language. What's wrong here? This is Windows 8. I can open Jupyter by jupyter notebook in cmd. It is opend in localhost:8888 with tree?token=somenumber successfully.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to click the new button on the right side to create a new python project/file. It is very confused, if you open python file directly and can't see the run cell option

[image: example]